# I can't see the div for the 1st object data using D3

Tags: d3.js

This is D3 code.
I have no idea what happens to 1st object(`"title":"lamda1"`).
Only I can see the div for 2nd object(`"title":"lamda2"`).

```
<script>
  var data = [{"title":"lamda1","indent":1,"R":1,"seq":29},
              {"title":"lamda2","indent":1,"R":2,"seq":29}], 
  colors =  d3.scale.category20();

d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("div")          
        .attr("id",function(d){return d.seq;})          
        .attr("class", "hcenter button button--aylen button--round-s button--border-thin button--size-m")
        .style("position","absolute")
        .style("width", "300px")
        .style("height", "50px")
        .style("line-height", "40px")
        .style("background-color", function (d, i) { return colors(i); })
        .style("color", "white")                    
        .text(function (d) { return d.title.slice(0,15); })
        .on("click", function(d){
            $(parent.document).find("#board_contents").attr("src","/lamda/board/board_selectOne.jsp?seq_board="+d.seq);
        });

d3.selectAll("div").each(function(d, i){
    d3.select(this)
        .transition().ease("cubic")
        .duration(500)
        .style("left", function(d){ return d.indent*20+"px";})
        .style("top", i*42+"px");           
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the snippet below, your code generates both divs (click "run code snippet").

What is probably happening in your real code is that you already have a `<div>` in your page. In that case, for assuring that your "enter" selection have all your data, select something else, like:

```
d3.select("body").selectAll(".somediv")
```

The reason for this is to avoid associating your data to an existent DOM element. Also, if you already have other divs in your document, mind your `d3.selectAll("div")` just before the `each` function.

Here is your working snippet:

```js
  var data = [{"title":"lamda1","indent":1,"R":1,"seq":29},
              {"title":"lamda2","indent":1,"R":2,"seq":29}], 
  colors =  d3.scale.category20();

d3.select("body").selectAll(".somediv")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("div")          
        .attr("id",function(d){return d.seq;})          
        .attr("class", "hcenter button button--aylen button--round-s button--border-thin button--size-m")
        .style("position","absolute")
        .style("width", "300px")
        .style("height", "50px")
        .style("line-height", "40px")
        .style("background-color", function (d, i) { return colors(i); })
        .style("color", "white")                    
        .text(function (d) { return d.title.slice(0,15); })
        .on("click", function(d){
            $(parent.document).find("#board_contents").attr("src","/lamda/board/board_selectOne.jsp?seq_board="+d.seq);
        });

d3.selectAll("div").each(function(d, i){
    d3.select(this)
        .transition().ease("cubic")
        .duration(500)
        .style("left", function(d){ return d.indent*20+"px";})
        .style("top", i*42+"px");           
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Really thank you... You are right. I see the 1st div as what you said.